# sublime-text-2-ruby-tests with Spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sublimetext2, spork

Am pretty new to Ruby on Rails. Am following the tutorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

The sublime-text-2-ruby-tests plugin test are very slow. How can we configure it to run with Spork to make them faster.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the guide at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-guard and works pretty well.
You will get extra shortcuts for the Sublime Text Editor 2 to run some tests.

For Linux those are:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>: run a single test (if run on an it block) or group of
  tests (if run on a describe block)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>: run the last test(s)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>: run all the tests in current file

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case it could be useful to someone.

Once sublime-text-2-ruby-test plugin is installed, browse Sublime: Preferences -> Package Settings -> RubyTest -> Settings - Default.

In that file, change "run_rspec_command": "rspec {relative_path}" to "run_rspec_command": "bundle exec rspec {relative_path} --drb"